# React - functional component does not return updated variable values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class Component FooPage which renders an imported functional Component BarForm. I pass handleSubmit as a prop to BarForm and want to capture the inputData value. The issue is the value is returned as the initial value.

To help debugging: before I submit, the latest value of inputData was logged correctly, and the submit did not trigger re-rendering. Still, FooPage console logs "initial value". What's more, changing onSubmit callback from `handleSubmit(inputData)` to arrow function `(event) => handleSubmit(inputData)(event)` fixes the problem.

While I know I can achieve this by `useState`, I want to understand why the updated inputData is returned as initial value even without re-rendering, and why using arrow function  as callback fixed the problem.

```js
const BarForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  let inputData = "initial value"
  console.log("I just re-rendered.") //Check BarForm did not re-render when submit.
  return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(inputData) }> {/* won't work, but arrow function does */}
      <input
        onChange = {(event) => {
          inputData = event.target.value; //update inputData
          console.log(inputData); //confirm the value of inputData before submit
        }}
        />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button> {/* But */}
    </form>
  )
}

class FooPage extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (inputData) => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); //Don't re-render
    console.log(inputData); //See the output 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BarForm handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FooPage />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions/  it's a little long, but I suggest you read it. Here are the solutions to your questions.

Comment: what were you expecting?  handleSubmit(inputData) returns with inputData variable set to the value  it was first called with.  Whereas a function wrapper doesn't evaluate the value of inputData until it is called.  inputData exists within the scope of the BarForm function, so the same inputData variable is available to all functions within that scope

Comment: Hi @user120242, "handleSubmit(inputData) returns with inputData variable set to the value it was first called with. Whereas a function wrapper doesn't evaluate the value of inputData until it is called." - this looks like what's wrong with my code. Could you please refer me to any documentations for furthur reading?

Comment: I don't think there will be any docs that will explain this well.  There's some blogs on "JavaScript closures variable scopes", but I don't really think they're very helpful.  Other than understanding scopes by looking at the code (and unseeing more strict variable habits you might have from other languages) I don't think there's a better way to understand it.  https://es6console.com/kaykntrz/  You can see that it runs handleSubmit(inputData) and sets the return value as the onSubmit properties value

Comment: also, short of using setState to trigger the render loop mutating inputData's value at the beginning of each call to the render function, encapsulating in another function is the best solution you will be able to achieve, because you need it to evaluate inputData at the time when onSubmit is called (after onChange changes it), not when the render function is called (before onChange has triggered).

Comment: @user120242 Thank you so much! I will keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(inputData) }>`, what you are actually doing in this case is calling the `handleSubmit` from `FooPage` function which returns a new function with `inputData` as captured when the component was first rendered as part of the function's scope.

When you call it with the arrow function, you don't actually create a new function when the component renders. You create the function `onSubmit`.

Comment: Soc thank you for your answer. Would you by chance know any articles/posts that elaborates on the difference of behaviros?